# How to go about Foundation framework installation

Tags: windows-installer, frontend, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Am new to web development and programming.

For 3 day now I have trying to get foundation up and running on my PC(windows 10 x64) but it not working.

I followed the documentation on their website but it didn't  work.

I downgraded from node12 to node8 and the foundation-cli installation was OK.

But running  "foundation new", it says "node modules not installed", with option to run "npm install" indicated  on the terminal
Please what should  I do?
[image: what is shown interest terminal]

Comment: Please run `npm i` manually. Afaik the gulp versions are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `npm i` manually. Afaik the gulp versions (of the Foundation CLI and Foundation Sites) are incompatible.